# round number to 3 decimal points (only if necessary)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Instead of `Math.round()` and `toFixed()`, what is the alternative way to maintain 3 decimal if only divisible number contain decimal.

I want to have

1. `100 / 30 => 3.333`
2. `390 / 100 => 3.90`
3. `100 / 100 => 1`

Comment: Why should it be `3.90` and not `3.9` ?

Comment: what type do you like to get?

Comment: I don't think you have another way around `toFixed()` - `3.9` is the actual numeric result of `390 / 100` and if you would like to show it as `3.90` or `3.900000` that is formatting for display not rounding.

Comment: as @Zenoo says, there seems to be a hidden rule for 2 decimals? in which condition exactly you want 2 decimals like `3.90`?

Answer (score 2):

You could fix the decimals and replace last zeroes with dot, if necessary.

```js
function round(n) {
    return function (v) {
       return v.toFixed(n).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
    };
}

var array = [100 / 30, 390 / 100, 100 / 100, 100];

console.log(array.map(round(3)));
```

With a first keeping zero.

```js
function round(n) {
    return function (v) {
       return v.toFixed(n).replace(/0+$/, '0').replace(/\.0+$/, '');
    };
}

var array = [100 / 30, 390 / 100, 100 / 100, 100];

console.log(array.map(round(3)));
```

Comment: I think the second options is enough. But toFixed return a string which I need to parse it again as numerical format